# ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage not available in PnP PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

I have SP 2019 environment with "**SharePointPnPPowerShell2019**" version 3.15.1911.0 installed. I need to transform the classic pages into modern pages. The cmdlets "ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage" is not available. Can anyone help me with this? Is there any other way other than PnP PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

The command "ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage" is only available for SharePoint online.

By design, we can't convert classic page to modern page in SharePoint 2019. There seems to be no other way to acheieve this, I suggest you create a modern page in a modern site.